# "The job is currently being throttled by the server. You may experience delays in console line output, job status reporting, and task log uploads"

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We currently have a self hosted build agent for azure devops.  A single agent was not sufficient for our needs as we are moving everything on-prem to azure.  I added another disk to our virtual machine that was being used as the self hosted agent on azure.  I configured a second agent on it and now we have two self host build agents for our devops azure pipeline.  However I started to see this warning :

### [Warning 1]

The job is currently being throttled by the server. You may experience delays in console line output, job status reporting, and task log uploads.

The warning gives you a link but does not really tell me why its being throttled.  It would be good to know so I can try to fix it.  So far this throttling only affects log output.  Just curious why it would be throttled.  Network throttling perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If your pipelines are in private project, the free tier is one [parallel job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#how-a-parallel-job-is-consumed-by-a-pipeline).It means it allows users in that organization to collectively run only one job at a time and there is only one job in job server queue. Azure DevOps hooks up JobServerQueueThrottling event and log warning on server tarpit.It is not Network throttling. Here is the source code [ExecutionContext.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/6754fbaa924536b5ebc7ff3bdd96bbc4dbf03f4e/src/Agent.Worker/ExecutionContext.cs)

Comment: I don't think this is the case.  If you have only 1 parallel job then you can only run jobs sequentially.  We have two agents running builds/releases in parallel because each agent gets to run 1 job each at the same time.

Comment: For others seeing this message, the code that initiates the message is triggered here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/c6f06f9decfddadcea8d8e54eb371cfb35fcd7c8/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent/ThrottlingReportHandler.cs#L61